# pygame.mixer.Sound.play: Unable to open file

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I have a problem with the play()-function of pygame.mixer.Sound()
When I use the code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# ~*~ coding: utf-8 ~*~

import pygame
import os

pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join("sound", "throw.wav"))

sound.play()
```

There is a black window (like i want), but it doesn't play the sound "throw.wav"
The strange about it is, that in the same directory is another sound named
"punch.wav", which works totally fine.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is a problem with the sound file. I had a .wav file which started to work with pygame after conversion to .ogg format. You can use [media.io](http://media.io/) to try it out.